# wait() not signaled by notify() in callback

Tags: java, android, callback, thread-synchronization

The problem is simple. On Android I have a method that needs to call a library function. The call will signal a callback that I must handle. Before I return from my method, I must wait for that callback to be signaled.

I thought the wait() and notify() methods on a monitor object would do the trick. It does not.

Basically the monitoring object is called `Connection` which I instantiate in the calling method. The method then does a loop where it calls an Android library method to 'unregister' an object. Unfortunately the response to this method is given in some callback. So I use the `Connection.wait(10000)` method to wait for the callback, and in the callback I use `connection.notify()` to signal when it gets done (all synchronized, of course). However, the `connection.notify()` does not release the `connection.wait(10000)`. I can see from the Android logcat that the unregistration succeeds BUT I always have to wait 10 seconds before the next unregisration task is attempted.

The code for the calling method and the callback are below. What stupid assumption am I making in my reasoning that this fails. As far as I can see the calling method (thread) definitely owns the monitoring Object and gives it up to the callback on the `connection.wait(10000)`!

Maybe I am using an entirely incorrect approach for this problem? (What I want is the method to block the caller until all the unregistrations are done.)

```
public void clearRegistrations()
{
    connection = new Connection();
    // Tell the callback to notify() when a result is obtained
    connection.setUseNotify(true);
    for(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration btConfig : btHealthAppConfigs)
    {
        // Initialize Connection object to not connected
        connection.setConnectionState(false);
        if(btHealth.unregisterAppConfiguration(btConfig))
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized (connection) 
                {
                    connection.wait(10000);
                    // See if we were signaled or timed out
                    if(!connection.getConnectionState())
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Unregistration attempt timed out or failed; trying next un-registration");
                    }
                }
            }
            // This should not happen
            catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "The InterrupedException is signaled.");
            }
            // This should not happen.
            catch(IllegalMonitorStateException ime)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "wait() method threw an IllegalMonitorStateException. Message: " + ime.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Un-Registration API returned failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    btHealthAppConfigs.clear();
    connection.setConnectionState(false);
    connection.setUseNotify(false);
}
```

The callback is as follows and it is in the same class as the method above but it is one of those 'onSomeEvent()' that is so popular in Android:

```
    public void onHealthAppConfigurationStatusChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration btAppConfig, int status)
    {
        if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_FAILURE)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Un-Registration of the Bluetooth Health Application failed");
            if(connection.useNotify() == true)
            {
                synchronized (connection)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signal unregistration failure");
                    // just indicate signaled
                    connection.setConnectionState(true);
                    connection.notify();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Un-Registration of the Bluetooth Health Application successful");
            if(connection.useNotify() == true)
            {
                synchronized (connection)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signal unregistration success");
                    connection.setConnectionState(true);
                    connection.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose `connection.useNotify() / setNotify()` use a boolean field - how is that field declared? Is it volatile? Also: you should always call `wait` in a loop and unless you know for sure that there is only one thread waiting, you should use `notifyAll`.

Comment: And your life would be simpler if instead of using wait/notify you used the high level concurrent API (for example a CountdownLatch).

Comment: Yes it does. Those are just helpers to figure out whether or not the wait(10000) returned due to timeout or because the notify() did the task. Since wait() returns nothing there was no other way to tell. In the end the problem is that the calling method is waiting 10 seconds for every attempt.

Comment: Can you see "Signal unregistration failure" or "Signal unregistration success" in your logcat?

Comment: Yes I can see them. So that part is working okay. I am looking at the CountDownLatch in the meantime because that does seem a nicer way to perform this task that I need in many places. I just hope I can get it into that callback which is called by the Android library and not my code!

Comment: Are you using the same `connection` instance in both methods?

Comment: Yes. The connection instance is created in the method but shared as a class global

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!!! CountDownLatch is SOOOO much easier and it works! (Still might be nice to have an answer for the other!) Thanks for the hint. I have been working for hours on this.

Comment: Apart from switching to `notifyAll` I don't see anything obvious in the code you have posted (and I doubt it will solve the issue). Glad to know that the CDL worked for you.

Comment: Would like to post the CountDownLatch as the answer but there is no way to do that!!

Comment: Of course you can. And you can even accept your answer if you feel like it!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that might be wrong with this code: assylias got most of them.  The obvious thing is that you definitely need to use notifyAll, instead of notify.  notify restarts some thread waiting on a lock; notifyAll restarts them all.

useNotify and setConnectionState also need to be synchronized.  Also you need to guarantee that the instance of connection on which you are locking, is the same in both sections, and is the same one on which you call notify.  Lastly, you need to guarantee that the call to notify actually happens after the call to wait.

As far as approach, anytime you use such low-level tools, you ought to wonder if there isn't a better way.  There are several higher-level constructs that could do this more simply.  I would suggest that you try to re-design you code so that you don't wait on the callback.  Make the call, park the state somewhere, and then handle the callback when it happens.

Comment: I cannot eliminate the callback in this case. Its part of a library and I must wait until it is finished (preferably no Sleeps). I have successfully used the wait/notify as you see in this code except the wait() in the successful case was started in its own Thread that was created by the called method. Of course that did not block the method that created the thread. From the logcat messages it is clear that everything is happening as expected except the release of wait(). I am sure you are correct in the sense that the COnnection object is not owned by the caller for some reason.

Comment: @Brian: Not suggesting you eliminate the callback!  Just don't wait for it with a "wait".  Instead, park your state somewhere, do other stuff, and, when the callback occurs, pick it back up.  I suggest logging the id of the object on which you wait, synchronize, and notify.  My bet is that they are not the same object.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks G Blake. Using the CountDownLatch was SOOO easy I am ditching the wait/notify. I still would like to eventually find out what I am doing wrong ... when time allows.